# Ubuntu 13.04 Wireless Hotspot Problems

Tags: wireless, 13.04, networking, mobile-broadband, hot-spot

I had an Ubuntu 12.04 system which I recently upgraded to 13.04. I thought of trying to create a Wireless Hotspot that I could use to share my Mobile Broadband Connection with other devices. To that end, I went to the Network Settings -> Wireless Settings and pressed the Use a Hotpost button. But instead of asking me for a name of the hotspot connection and other details (as I had expected), the hotspot straight away asked me to turn the hotspot on. On doing so, I received a notification stating that I was now connected to the hotspot network and almost immediately afterwards it told me that I was disconnected from the network. The Wireless Network page still showed that I was connected to the specified hotspot. An idea on what might be going on with my system.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with Ubuntu 13.04. It is not connecting to other HotSpot.

But you can use `ap-hostspot` instead. Read [how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html) to install `ap-hotspot`.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.